# The data in API does not shown in the web part for User

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, spfx, sharepoint-rest-api, modern-experience

I am very new to SPFx web part creation.

I have created simple SPFx web part using typescript.

Added package to app catalog then added in my page.

The issue that I am facing is user doesn't read the content from API and it shown as NaN in the web part but as Admin can read the content of API and everything is fine.

I don't know how to give permission with SPFx to the user to be able to read data from API.

[image]

Comment: Which API are you using to fetch the data? You have to grant the permissions on the resource you are trying to fetch using API & it will automatically work in SPFx.

Comment: Thank you for your response.                                                                                           Im using:                                                                                                                 
   import {
  SPHttpClient,
  ISPHttpClientBatchOptions,
  SPHttpClientConfiguration,
  SPHttpClientResponse,
  ODataVersion,
  ISPHttpClientConfiguration,
} from "@microsoft/sp-http"; to fetch  the data

Comment: Are you fetching SharePoint list items? does other user have access on that SharePoint list?

Comment: I'm fetching  web properties and the Admin can just see the content from Api, it seems that the users don't have permission

Comment: In order to read the web properties using REST API, user should have at least read permissions on sharepoint site.

Answer (score 0):

We'd need more information to be able help you further, but it looks like you're probably receiving an error when calling the API and not handling the error.

Can you confirm that the API is getting *any* results? Can you use `console.log(data)` in your code to show the `data` you received from your API (or whatever variable name you use)?

When building and debugging, you want your error messages to be as loud as possible for you to be able to detect when. When in production, you want to handle the errors and display an appropriate message to let users know, but -- as a general rule -- I try to never ignore error messages in my code.

Let us know more and see how we can help!?

Answer (score 0):

The spfx web part it based on the current logged on user's permission. So if you are using rest api to get data, you need to grant enough permission to the user so he could acess the data.

Answer (score 0):

As per our discussion in comments section above,

You have to grant the permissions on the resource (web/site) you are trying to fetch using SharePoint API & it will automatically work in SPFx as the API calls from SPFx web part will be performed based on currently logged in users & their permissions.

So, in order to fetch the web properties using REST API, user should have at least **Read** permissions on SharePoint site.

**Microsoft Documentations**:

1. [User permissions and permission levels in SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/sites/user-permissions-and-permission-levels)
2. [Overview of the SharePoint Framework](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/sharepoint-framework-overview)